# Approximating $\int_0^1 \cos(x^2)dx$ with power series

Tags: integration, fresnel-integrals

I would like to calculate $\int_0^1 \cos(x^2)dx$ with an error smaller than $10^{-6}$ (this error should be proven.).

I have a strategy, but I am not quite sure if this is a valid one. Here is what I did:

I know that the series representation of the cosine is:$$\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
Since the integral boundaries I want to calculate only range from $0$ to $1$, I can use the fact that $a_k :=\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ is a falling sequence for $x \in [0,1]$. Then I would use the estimation from the Leibnitz criterion, that for positive falling $a_k$ with

$$s_n := \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k a_k$$
the inequality $|s - s_n|\le a_{n+1}$ holds, whereas $s$ denotes the limit of $s_k$.

Then I could say that for $n=9$:

$$|\cos(x)-s_9| \le \frac{1}{(2\cdot 10)!}$$

Then I would calculate $\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^9 (-1)^k \frac{x^{4k}}{(2k)!}dx$

The estimate I get seems to be correct, however I am not sure whether or not my prove above is sufficient. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it is correct, just be sure that $a_{10}\le10^{-6}$

Comment: @Masacroso Okay, thanks! I think I just realised that $n=4$ should suffice to be honest ^^

Comment: @Masacroso oh yes, I made a mistake in the question thanks again

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake in my previous comment... you must ensure that $a_n\le 10^{-6}$ for the integrated series. In the integrated series the coefficients are defined by $1/((4k+1)(2k)!)$, not by $1/(2k)!$

Comment: BTW, the error when stopping at $n=4$ is *pointwise* at most $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$, hence integrated from $0$ to $1$ at most $\frac1{11!}$, which is even way smaller than $10^{-7}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order of what what you're doing.  First integrate, then bound the series:

$$\int_0^1 \cos(x^2) \; dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k x^{4k}}{(2k)!} \; dx =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(4k+1)(2k)!}. $$

So the error in $s_n$ is bounded by $$\frac{1}{(4(n+1)+1)(2(n+1))!}.$$ 
And $n=4$ suffices.