# Find $\int_{0}^{1} \cos x^{2} \operatorname dx$ as power series and compute with $10^{-4}$ accuracy

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find the following indefinite integral as power series and then compute the definite integral 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \cos (x^{2}) dx$$ with the accuracy $10^{-4}$.

I would love to share my ideas regarding this problem, but unfortunately I do not have any, because this topic is kind of new to me and we have not solved similiar problems in our classes. So any help will be greatly appreciated and some day I can give your contribution back to the community as well :).

PS: I hope that the problem is still understandable, did my best to translate it from Finnish to English.

Comment: **Hints:** Try finding $\int_0^1 \cos\left(x^2\right)\, dx $ using the power series of $ \cos\left(x^2\right)$. You should obtain an alternating series, so the error by stopping after a finite number of terms [can be bounded above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Proof_of_partial_sum_error_bound) by the absolute value of the next term. Pick enough terms to make this bound less than $10^{-4}$. In fact, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328284/approximating-int-01-cosx2dx-with-power-series for a similar question.

Comment: Have you heard of power series and the Taylor development ? Can you integrate a polynomial ? Can you estimate the tail of an alternating series ?

Comment: "some day I can give your contribution back to the community as well" is not a useful comment.

Comment: Is the square placed on the $x$ or on $\cos x$? Do you mean $(\cos x)^2$ or $\cos(x^2)$?

Comment: I mean $\cos(x^{2})$ by that... I will change it in the task description as well. As far as my lectures go I have heard these things like Taylor development, polynomial integration and estimating the so called ''tail'' but we have not used them in practical exercises (thanks to COVID, because we haven't had any of them since March). 
The sentence ,,I can give your contribution back to the community'' seems important to say, because while posting the problem, the ground rules of this community want to point out why is it important to me and to the community... So... I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is a very well known result that:

$$\cos(x)=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}x^{2\text{k}}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\tag1$$

So:

$$\cos\left(x^2\right)=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}x^{4\text{k}}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\tag2$$

So, for the integral we get:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_0^1\cos\left(x^2\right)\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\int_0^1x^{4\text{k}}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\left[\frac{x^{4\text{k}+1}}{4\text{k}+1}\right]_0^1=$$
$$\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\left(\frac{1^{4\text{k}+1}}{4\text{k}+1}-\frac{0^{4\text{k}+1}}{4\text{k}+1}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(4\text{k}+1\right)\cdot\left(\left(2\text{k}\right)!\right)}\tag3$$

Now, we want to find:

$$\left|\mathcal{I}-\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\text{n}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(4\text{k}+1\right)\cdot\left(\left(2\text{k}\right)!\right)}\right|\le10^{-4}\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{n}\ge3\tag4$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}\approx\sum_{\text{k}=0}^3\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\left(4\text{k}+1\right)\cdot\left(\left(2\text{k}\right)!\right)}=\frac{25399}{28080}\tag5$$